User interface library for editor software
I need an open source library written in vanilla TypeScript or JavaScript (i.e., no requirement of frameworks such as React or Angular) for building user interface for editor software such as video editors, and graphics editors. I am using Electron with TypeScript through an ElectronForge template.
It must include handling of context menus, and the top menu bar. It is not required, but if possible, it would be nice for allowing custom style sheets (i.e., it is clear which CSS classes it uses).
